# HTC one mini 2 moves the FAB automatically

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I am trying out my FloatingActionButton on different phones. I noticed something really weird.

On my HTC one mini 2 (API 19). It automatically moves the FAB 16dp. But on my other phones sony xperia z5 (API 23) compact, One plus 2 (API 22) and samsung galaxy s4 (API 21). It does not move at all.

Then if i tell the XML to move it 16dp margins. It moves the FAB 32dp om my HTC one mini 2.

Could this be related to the API level 19?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It got fixed when i updated the Support library. So i guess there was a bug